# PFX size limit error on Azure application gateway configuration

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-aks, pfx, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to configure azure application gateway. I provided .pfx file for https listener configuration. But when i tried to create Azure application gateway, I am getting below error

```
   {
      "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
      "message": "The template deployment 'Microsoft.ApplicationGateway-20210324165226' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '808d9e19-ad0c-4a8a-a09f-df7c0bc38399'. See inner errors for details.",
      "details": [
        {
          "code": "ApplicationGatewaySslCertificateDataTooBig",
          "message": "Data too big for certificate /subscriptions/yyy/resourceGroups/xxx-resources/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/app-gateway/sslCertificates/my-pfx. Max data length supported is 16384.",
          "details": []
        }
      ]

}
```

Could anyone help here?

Comment: My certificate is 12526 but when b64 encoded the size is 16704. The v2 sku limit is 16k. So my cert goes over the size limit when its base64 encoded and they appear to use the encoded size rather than the decoded cert size.

Comment: It turns out, while the above may be true, I was converting a PEM to a PFX and intending to send the PFX to app gateway but was accidentally sending the PEM, which is larger. Sending the pfx fixed it. Here is the code to convert a pem to a app gateway compatible pfx:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -passin "pass:$V_CERT_PASSWORD" -passout "pass:$V_CERT_PASSWORD" -in $PEM_FILE -out $PFX_FILE`

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar problem trying to upload a 14209 bytes .pfx file containing a 4096 bits key to Azure Application Gateway, the root and intermediate certificates. The upload was refused with the following error:

> Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway: Data too big for certificate. Max data length supported is 16384.

After removing the root and intermediate certificates from the .pfx file, the file size decreased to 9793 bytes and upload to Azure Application Gateway succeeded. TLS works as expected.

My conclusion: there is no limitation on the key size itself, but there is a .pfx file size limit.

Comment: How does one remove root and intermediate certificates?

Comment: How can TLS work without the root and intermediates also?

Comment: suppose mycert.pfx is the orginal pfx certificate 

2a. We have to split pfx into .crt and .key 

openssl pkcs12 -in mycert -clcerts -nokeys -out mycert-lean.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert -nocerts -out mycert-lean.key

2b. Combine .crt and .key again to get a single pfx certificate of reduced size

'openssl pkcs12 -export -out  mycert-lean.pfx -inkey mycert-lean.key  -in mycert-lean.crt'

Comment: @Ast comment should be the approved answer since it doesn't require any manual edition of the files.